# Remove a terminated SCA from all SharePoint site collections, including OneDrive for Business

Tags: sharepoint-online

When the "Set-SPOUser -Site $Site.Url -LoginName XXXXXX@xxx.com -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $False" script ran getting the error: "Set-SPOUser : The user does not exist or is not unique"

Answer (score 0):

Whether the Login Name is a user or a group?

If a user, whether you can run Set-SPOUser command for only one site at a time?

If a group, you need to use SID of the group as the login name as the following article: [How to resolve error "The user does not exist or is not unique." when use Set-SPOUser for SharePoint online?](http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-to-resolve-error-user-does-not.html)